# Send https get request

Tags: java, https

I am working on a crawler and I have the following question: it works with simple HTTP requests, but not HTTPS, and I need to make an HTTPS request. I changed the port to 443 and try to send the same request, but I get 400 error. Obviously, I need to change something else, but I do not know what. I open socket and this is how I make the request:

```
String request
        = "GET " + file
        + (file.endsWith("robots.txt") ? " HTTP/1.0\r\n" : " HTTP/1.1\r\n")
        //                " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        + "User-Agent: " + CrawlerConfig.USER_AGENT + "\r\n"
        //                + ((!CrawlerConfig.SAVE_IMAGES) ? "Accept: text/html\r\n" : "")
        //                + "Accept: text/*\r\n"
        + (file.endsWith("robots.txt") ? "Connection: close\r\n" : "")
        + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "\r\n"/*
         * + body
         */;

outStream.write(request.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
outStream.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send an OPTIONS request on the resource, needed request headers should be returned, some may be missing.